# c++ templates and inheritance, can templates be more selective

Tags: c++, templates

Can templates be limited to a class that inherits from other class.

for example `template<T>`, T must inherit from  Foo in order to be used in a template function or class.

For example I have a class that requires a controller, this controller will be created in class constructor, but I need to know the type of a controller, and it must conform to an interface (inherit).

`View<T>` where T is a controller type that must inherit from a generic controller class

Comment: Why do you need this? Doesn't the template not compiling for a given template parameter give enough indication that the template parameter was wrong? (The compiler should even tell you which part of your code contains the issue.

Comment: Yes, in so many ways, your request is not specific enough.  What have you tried?  What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only allow only `T`s that derive from a certain interface you can use SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error). Here is an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived : Base {};

struct NotDerived {};

template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base,T>>>
struct TClass {};

int main ()
{
    TClass<Derived> tc1;
    // TClass<NotDerived> tc2; // compiler error
}
```

If you have c++20 concepts then you can do the following:

```
template<typename T>
concept DerivedFromBase = std::is_base_of_v<Base,T>;

template <DerivedFromBase T>
struct TClass {};
```

If you use a type which does not inherit from `Base` you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: in c++20 there is also constraints that allow direct interface specification without checking the base of. for example template<Foo T>. but ram stuck with c14 so yeah enable if t helps but have no idea how it works :)

Comment: @AntonStafeyev Thank you for pointing this out, I haven't heard of this yet. I also saw you tried to edit my answer, I rejected it, because you changed it to ```std::is_base_of_v<Base,T>::value``` which is wrong. To use it with c++14 you have to write ```std::is_base_of<Base,T>::value``` without the c++ 17 ```_v```.

Comment: @yeah sorry man didn't notice _v extension :)

Answer (score 2):

C++20 and never:

- Replace `template <typename T>` with `template <std::derived_from<MyClass> T>`.

  This requires `#include <concepts>`.

Pre-C++20:

- Replace `template <typename T>` with this:

  ```
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<MyClass, T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
  ```

  Here, `std::is_base_of_v<...>` requires at least C++17. If you don't have that, use `std::is_base_of<...>::value` instead. It does the same thing, but requires more typing.

Any C++ version:

- Add `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<MyClass, T>, "Your error message");` inside of the class/template.

  The big downside of this approach is that it makes it impossible to programatically determine if a template accepts a specific type without triggering the error. All other approaches above allow that.

  On the other hand, it lets you display a custom error message.